# Extract values from oddly formatted line in external file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, key, key-value

I am working with a third party device's output data (location and IMU info). The file has several thousand lines of the following example data. I have the file read and loop working, but I'm having difficulties extracting the values from each of the keys in the following data:

```
[color_md : default] [latitude: 52.365056] [longtitude: -1.202661] [rel_alt: -0.000 abs_alt: 136.471] [Drone: Yaw:-123.7, Pitch:-2.8, Roll:1.2]
```

So I can eventually have a variable value for each of the keys, i.e:

```
latitude = 52.365056
longtitude = -1.20266
yaw = -123.7
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can filter out the numerical values from the line and create an array of them using regex:

```
dataSet = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", stripped_line)
```

Produces an array as follows:

```
['52.365056', '-1.202661', '0.000', '136.471', '-123.7', '-2.8', '-1.2']
```

As the data is consistent I can map these array postions to create the variables I require. E.g.

```
latitude = dataSet[0]
```

Comment: If you want to get the value associated with a particular 'key' (e.g. latitude) you could use this:-

r'(?<=\[latitude: )(.*?)(?=\])'